# Asking facebook for data of multiple users in single request using FB.api

Tags: facebook

I need to get basic user data from Facebook using `FB.api('/<some_id>/')`. This works well, but is slow, since I need to ask for every id separately and make several calls to facebook. Is there any way to gather all ids and ask for them in single request and get an array?

**EDIT**

I am not asking for user friends. I am actually trying to gather friends' friends of a user and that's something Facebook doesn't provide, that's why I am using `graph.facebook.com/<id>/` rather than `graph.facebook.com/me/friends`. I don't want friends, I'd like to do something like this: `graph.facebook.com/<id1>,<id2>,<id3>,../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `FQL`:

From the Facebook examples:

```
var friends = FB.Data.query(
     "(select uid2 from friend where uid1 = {0})",
     user_id);

var friendsoffriends = FB.Data.query(
     "select uid2 from friend where uid1 in (select uid2 from {0})",
     friends;

 // Now, register a callback
 FB.Data.waitOn([friends, friendsoffriends], function() {   
   // now display all the results
   FB.Array.forEach(friendsoffriends.value, function(row) {
       console.log(row.uid);
   });
 });
```

Then edit for whatever collection of ids you wish to use.

The above approach remains valid (as a reasonable generic example) - however, to clarify:

You would previously have used [users.getInfo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/) to do what you are asking, as this allows you to pass a list of UIDS. Unfortunately this is being deprecated. However, all this query *actually* does is wrap an FQL query.

If you then apply the standard FQL 'in' syntax you can achieve this:

```
{
myfriends:'select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()',
friendsoffriends:'select uid2 from friend where uid1 in (select uid2 from #myfriends)'
}
```

However facebook actively prevents you from doing this with the error:

```
"error_code": 604,
  "error_msg": "Can't lookup all friends of 123456789. Can only lookup for the logged in user (987654321), or friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission",
```

Your other option is to get all of the ids and do an FQL query of the form:

```
select name from user where uid='123456789' OR uid='987654321' OR uid=...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an fql query to get info on all friends:

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_small FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

If you prompt the user for more extended permissions you would be able to get access to more fields from the [user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/).

If you are trying to query a list of arbritary user ids that aren't the users friends, you could try specifiying that list in the FQL query for use Facebooks [FQL Multiquery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/) capability, doing multiple `select uid, name from user where uid = friendid1` statements.

Comment: Even with what I think you mean in your edit, this FQL approach is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

FQL is no longer supported but this method does the trick in the new api:

[Requesting multiple Facebook fanpage data in a single call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915225/requesting-multiple-facebook-fanpage-data-in-a-single-call)

In short use `ids` param:

```
FB.api(
    '/', 
    {ids : "19292868552,11239244970"}, 
    function(response) { 
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response.error); 
        } else { 
            console.log(response); 
        } 
    }
);
```